# Rough vertical ridges

Tags: print-quality, ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3

I sometimes have a problem with rough surfaces. This problem can show up any time on vertical surfaces.

In the linked picture of the problem, the area further from the camera has ridges that are sharp and clean. It is usually  in one area on the outer surface of curving shapes. Could anyone tell me what the name of this effect is and how to avoid it? I'm using an Ender 3 and Cura.

[image]

Comment: have you tightened your belts and checked the extruder ways?

Comment: Looks like underextrusion caused by oozing elsewhere or "coasting" enabled in Cura. Can you add all retraction, combing, and coasting settings to the question body?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like under extrusion, here's a extreme example.

[image]

I would check your feed rate by marking out 100 mm on the filament then manually extruding 100 mm. You can use this to verify if you are under extruding due to your feeder. If you find that the printer only fed say 90 mm when you asked for 100 mm, you will need to change your feed rate in Cura to 110 %.

If you confirm that the printer is pulling 100 mm through when you manually ask for that much, then it could be a combination of speed, cooling & jitter. I would slow down the print speed and see if it improves the print quality. I've experienced issues where the nozzle is moving fast around small bends and wobbling slightly, the filament is struggling to land on the previous layer and the resulting effect looked a bit like your photo.

I can't think of anything else that might be causing this issue.

Comment: I kicked the feed rate up to 105% and replaced the nozzle. These actions seem to have fixed the issue.